# PrePended button to multiple divs does not open popin for all

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button that tiggers a popin. I appended it to a div and then preppended that div to all divs with the same class.

My problem is that only the last button prepended triggers the popin. The other buttons dont seem to work.

Can anyone help me?

[JSFiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/m3jtknzL/3/)

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}


$(window).on('load', function() {
  function topBannerCaps() {
    if ($('#container').css('display') == 'block') {
    
      $('#myBtn').appendTo('#container');
    }
    $('#container').prependTo('.test-div');
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(topBannerCaps);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of problem in your code.

1. Id must be unique so use `class` on button instead of `id` when append.
2. Don't mismatch JavaScript and jQuery.
3. Avoid inline class if possible.

Working Fiddle:

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = $("#myModal");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = $(".myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = $(".close");

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.on("click", () => {
  $(modal).css("display", "block")
});


// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.on("click", () => {
  $(modal).css("display", "none")
});

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    $(modal).css("display", "none")
  }
}


$(window).on('load', function() {
  function topBannerCaps() {
    if ($('#container').css('display') == 'block') {
      btn.appendTo('#container');
    }
    $('#container').prependTo('.test-div');
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(topBannerCaps);
});
```

```css
.modal {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px;
  /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
}


/* Modal Content */

.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
}


/* The Close Button */

.close {
  color: #aaaaaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button class="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
  </div>

</div>

<div id="container" style="display: block"></div>


<div class="example">
  <div class="test-div">Example DIV</div>
  <div class="test-div">Example DIV</div>
  <div class="test-div">Example DIV</div>
  <div class="test-div">Example DIV</div>
  <div class="test-div">Example DIV</div>
  <div class="test-div">Example DIV</div>
</div>
```